# How to compile GNU sed without dll?

Tags: compilation, sed, mingw, gnu

I compiled the [GNU sed](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/sed/) with [MinGW+MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/):

```
./configure
make && make install
```

and it worked.

But what has come to trouble me is that the sed.exe can not run without libintl-8.dll libiconv-2.dll.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You could also say that sed.exe doesn't run without kernel32.dll but you can't link against that! 

Do you have the source for those 2 dlls?  It will be possible to compile them as .lib and then change sed to link against them.

Sorry, not much help, but what you are asking is possible.

Comment: Type `./configure --help` and watch for possible switches containing `static`. It's possible there is a configure switch that forces static linking. That's what you're looking for.

Comment: Before asking this question, I have tried.no "static" can be found.   :(

Answer (score 1):

```sh
./configure LDFLAGS=-static
make
```

[`ref`](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/master/scripts/install-rtmpdump.sh)